# Is $|9x-1|^3$ differentiable at $1/9$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I think it is, but I'm stuck at showing it. I know that it is equal to:

$$|9x - 1|  \cdot |9x - 1|^2.$$

$|9x - 1|$ is not differentiable at $1/9$, and I am pretty sure that $|9x - 1| ^2$ is differentiable there.

Comment: Did you try checking that directly using the definition?

Comment: yes I did, still can't see it

Comment: Well, it could be the same as the checking for $|9x-1|^2$.

Comment: If you could show us what you tried, we can probably help you get the rest of the way fairly easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look separately at the limits of $\frac{f(x)-f(1/9)}{x-1/9}$ (for $x\neq 1/9$) on both sides of $1/9$: the goal is to see if they *exist*, and (if so) if they are the *same*. If this is the case, then $f$ is differentiable at $1/9$, and $f^\prime(1/9)$ equals this common limit.

See below for more details. The hidden parts can be revealed by placing your mouse over them.

---

Start by factorizing $(9x-1)^3$ to make a factor $x-\frac{1}{9}$ appear:

> $$(9x-1)^3 = 9\left(x-\frac{1}{9}\right)(9x-1)^2$$

- For $x > \frac{1}{9}$, $\lvert 9x-1\rvert^3 = (9x-1)^3$, so that

  > $$\frac{f(x) - f(\frac{1}{9})}{x-\frac{1}{9}} = \frac{(9x-1)^3-0}{x-\frac{1}{9}} = 9(9x-1)^2 \xrightarrow[x\to1/9^+]{} 0$$
- For $x < \frac{1}{9}$, $\lvert 9x-1\rvert^3 = (1-9x)^3 = -(9x-1)^3$, so that

  > $$\frac{f(x) - f(\frac{1}{9})}{x-\frac{1}{9}} = -\frac{(9x-1)^3-0}{x-\frac{1}{9}} = -9(9x-1)^2 \xrightarrow[x\to1/9^-]{} 0$$

Therefore, the limits on both sides exist and coincide: $f^\prime(1/9)=\lim_{x\to1/9}\frac{f(x) - f(\frac{1}{9})}{x-\frac{1}{9}}$ thus exists.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you a more general perspective. Consider a smooth (say $C^1$) function $h$ and define $f(x)=h(|x|)$. By assumption,
$$
h(u) = h(0)+\left( h'(0) + \omega(u) \right)u,
$$
where $\lim_{u \to 0} \omega (u)=0$. Hence
$$
f(x) = h(|0|) + \left( h'(0) + \omega(|x|) \right) |x|
$$
and therefore $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ if and only if $h'(0)=0$. This is the case for $h(u)=u^3$.

Comment: There is an extra |x| after the Hence, isn't there?

Answer (score 2):

Its quite easy and same as checking for $f(x)=|x-1/9|^3$.

For $x>1/9$
$f(x)=(x-1/9)^3$
Differentiate w.r.t x and put $x=1/9$.Say the value of the derivative is $a$.

For $x<1/9$
$f(x)=-(x-1/9)^3$
Differentiate w.r.t x and put $x=1/9$.Say the value of the derivative is $b$.

If $a=b$ then it is differentiable at $x=1/9$

This method works because $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1/9$